# How to make CSV data set to use only 1 value per user in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a script wherein I need to execute the "Extract Token" API at the 1st iteration and 30th Iteration for each user and I used if controller. Now the problem is I need to pass this extracted token to execute some other APIs. For the first iteration, there is no issue but from 2nd iteration onwards, the other APIs are failing as they are still using the token extracted for iteration 1 (say member A) whereas JMeter uses member B in API request, and for iteration 3, member c and so on (token and member id mismatch). To solve this issue, I need to set CSV data set to use only 1 fixed value for each user (say if I execute a test with 10 users, only 10 values need to be allocated from my data file). Please help how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - by default it will read next line from the file on each iteration of the each virtual user (this behaviour can be amended via [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) setting)

However "sticking" one virtual user to a specific line in the CSV file is not something you can get with the CSV Data Set Config. You can alternatively consider using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()),)}
```

this way 1st user will read 1st line, 2nd user - 2nd line, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T, ${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()),)} did the job!!